# Script gives "if: command not found"

Tags: bash

I have a script like this:

```
HI="if [[ $(ioreg -r -k AppleClamshellState | grep '"AppleClamshellState"' | cut -f2 -d"=") = ' Yes' ]]; then ./lockscreen; fi"
while true; do $HI; sleep 1; done
```

Running `bash ./test` gives `if: command not found`. Replacing the outer double quotes with single quotes and the inner single quotes with `'\''` also has the same problem.

Setting `HI` to `echo Hello` or `rm -rf *.mp4` works fine.

Setting `HI='if [ "" = "" ]; then echo Hi; fi'` similarly fails.

It seems that because of the quotes, it assumes `if` is the command name, and everything else after it is an argument. I need a way to expand it out.

The point of this is that I want to make a function `Loop` that takes a string as an argument, and will execute that string every 10 seconds.

Comment: I think instead of a variable, you may want a [function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html) named `HI`?

Comment: @JNevill This is just a minimal viable example of the problem -- this is part of a larger script where I use variables to pass in functions.

Comment: do any parts of your *larger script* work with this type of functionality and if so could you update the question to include an example where this works

Comment: Don't store commands in variables. As @JNevill says, functions are better. See: [BashFAQ/050 - I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: You need an alias or function, or to eval a string. Strings aren't commands, and won't be parsed as such by the shell's interpreter.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I can solve this by using `do eval "$HI"`. Of course, the problem is that if I use double quotes, then expansions are done at the first run. I don't want it to be expanded, but evaluated at every run.

EDIT: I got around this by using `\$`, or even better, using single quotes (this did mean I had to escape all the single quotes though).

EDIT 2: After consideration, I just decided to use functions without `eval` -- dealing with escaping was not worth it.

Comment: Not my DV, but this also opens you up to the many [downsides of `eval`.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). The suggested alternatives in the linked [BashFAQ/050](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) are strongly preferrable - for example, use a function instead.

Comment: If you really must use `eval`, at least double-quotes the variable reference. Without that, you get even sillier problems than `eval` usually brings.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I usually would -- but double quotes expands out expressions before I want them to.

Comment: @DrownedSuccess I mean you should use double-quotes in the `eval` command, i.e. use `eval "$HI"` instead of just `eval $HI`. Without those, with a command like `HI="echo '2 * 2 = 4'"`, the `*` will expand to a list of files in the current directory (yes, even though it's in two layers of quotes) (unless you happen to have any homework from [Wilhelmina '$(rm -R Students)' Roberts](https://xkcd.com/327/) in your current directory, in which case something more annoying will happen).

Comment: More generally, to use `eval` like this safely, you need to understand how the command will be parsed & transformed through three layers of processing: 1) as the variable ie defined, 2) as the variable is expanded before it's passed to `eval`, and 3) as it's parsed again by `eval`, as well as how those three layers interact with each other. Understanding this is *really hard*, and if you get it wrong you're basically working in a minefield of bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Creating the loop function is straightforward. Calling it is the tricky part.

Here `"$@"` is the expansion of the arguments passed to `loop`. It's the same as writing `"$1" "$2" "$3" ...` for however many arguments there actually are:

```
loop() {
    while true; do
        "$@"
        sleep 10
    done
}
```

As you've experienced, variable expansion like this works fine for regular commands, but doesn't handle more complicated cases like `if` statements, `|` pipelines, `&&` and `||` operators, or multi-line commands separated with `;` and/or `&`.

The best way to support all of those features is for the caller to define a function and pass the function name to `loop`. Functions can use all of these features, and have the advantage of not requiring any complicated quoting or escaping:

```
hi() {
    if [[ $(ioreg -r -k AppleClamshellState | grep '"AppleClamshellState"' | cut -f2 -d"=") = ' Yes' ]]; then
        ./lockscreen
    fi
}

loop hi
```

Further reading:

- [BashFAQ/050: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)